# XPATH: exclude elements which which has a specific child

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<ul>
  <li><a></li>
  <li><a></li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I select only first 2 li items and exclude **li** that contains div inside?

Considering **ul** is set as parent, I've tried

```
./li[not(contains(descendant::div]
```

But obviously that didn't work

Comment: how about `li[0]` and `li[1]`

Comment: try with the xpath //ul/li/a/..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `contains` and use `//` instead of `./`

```
//li[not(descendant::div)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Xpath that searches for `li` tags that has not `div` child:

```
//li[not(descendant::div)]
```

another option:

```
//li[not(.//div)]
```

To exclude some elements from selection - use `not()` method like `locator[not(condition)]`

Some more complex example on this table https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp: 
here is locator that gets row that has not elements inside with text that starts with "C"

```
//table[@id='customers']//tr[not(.//*[starts-with(text(),'C')])]
```

explanation:

> `//table[@id='customers']//tr` - get all rows
>
> `[not(.//*[...])]` - not containing element with specific attribute
>
> `[starts-with(text(),'C')]` - and that the described attribute

Comment: do add an explanation as to what those statements do, it helps the asker a lot

Comment: they do actually what was asked in the topic)  - exclude elements which has a specific child. Ok i'll add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
//li[not(contains(div,' '))]
```

This works for me.

your code:

> ./li[not(contains(descendant::div]

is missing some ')', should have been:

```
./li[not(contains(descendant::div))]
```